# Hosting Laravel Application on Ubuntu Server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, hosting

I have recently developed my first Laravel application (version 5.2.).

I now want to host the application on my client's server running Ubuntu.

Their admin managed to install and run the native Laravel application on the server which works just fine, however when I come to copy and paste my own application over, the browser returns:

> 403 Forbidden
>
> nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Accessing the public folder directly (`www.example.com/public/index.php`) the browser returns:

> The www.example.com page isn’t working
>
> www.example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

Can anybody please help me out with the proper method of hosting my application?

Answer (score 2):

Seems more like an nginx-problem. Try to change your nginx virtualhost config to this.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name yoursite.tld

        root /var/www/yoursite/public/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First save your file inside,

> var/www/html/

Then using Terminal go to your folder
`cd var/www/html/your_folder`

Run Laravel application

```
sudo php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

**Make sure your port number is not same as the other Laravel instance running in the server.**